# Add Holidays to Outlook 2007 Calendar

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2007, calendar

So I can happily add UK Holidays to my Outlook 2007 Calendar without problems using Tools->Options->Calendar Option->Add Holiday.

So far so good.

A user has raised the query that if you create a second calendar (in this case for the purposes of team holiday) the UK Public Holidays are not automatically added to it.  I have tried just readding the UK Holidays using the method above but it only adds them to the default calendar and not subsequently created calendars.  Does anyone know how to achieve this or am I stuck with getting them to manually create the entries?

So far all my searches turn up the information I already know.  Having serious Google-fu issues this morning it seems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well its not the best solution but the  only one I have found so far.  Basically there is no way to do this via the options but instead the holiday entries can be copied and pasted from one to the other.

Easiest way to do this and get all the entries in one hit is to place your original calendar in view "By Category", select the Holiday category and copy to the clipboard.  Load up the other calendar and paste the entries there.  Not perfect but as one helpful user on the internet pointed out "its always been like this".  Not really sure why it has to continue to be so though :)  Still hopefully this may help someone out in the future.